# htmlaqulitypack Как выбирать внутренние Ветки среди массива Ветвей

Tags: c#, html

Структура такая:

```
<div class="level1">
       <div class="level2">11</div>
       <div class="level2">12</div>
</div>
<div class="level1">
       <div class="level2">21</div>
       <div class="level2">22</div>
       <div class="level2">23</div>
</div>
    <div class="level1">
        <div class="level2">33</div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы выводило: "11 21 33"

Но выводит: "11 11 11"

В чём ошибка?

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='level1']");

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
           string s =  node.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='level2']").InnerText;
           Console.Write (s+ " ");
          // По идее должно вывести: "11 21 33"
          // Но выводит: "11 11 11" 
        }
```

Comment: а попробуйте "./div[@class='level2']"

Comment: У меня ваш код отрабатывает как положено. Ищите ошибку в другом месте. http://prnt.sc/e176pg